# Powershell scripts invoked by C# application

Tags: c#, scripting, powershell, pipeline, runspace

I have this powershell script (test1.ps1) calling another powershell script(test2.ps1) to do the job.

Both scriptfiles are in the same folder

**test1.ps1**

```
echo "from test1.ps1"

.\test2.ps1
```

**test2.ps1**

```
echo "from test2.ps1"
```

When I invoke test1.ps1 in C# by creating runspace, adding commands to pipeline and invoking it, I get an error message saying 
**"The term '.\test2.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."**

Comment: Please show the code you use to invoke the scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Both the scripts might be in the same folder, but `.\test2.ps1` will look for test2.ps1 in the same folder as the calling application, which is the C# app.

Have this in test.ps1:

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
.$scriptdir\test2.ps1
```